# Estimating $P(A,B|X)$ given $P(A|X)$, $P(B|X)$ and $P(B|A)$

Tags: probability, statistics, estimation

I have to deal with a situation where I have the following knowledge:

- $P(A)$
- $P(B)$
- $P(A|X)$
- $P(B|X)$
- $P(B|A)$

I do now want to compute $P(A,B|X)$.
Firstly, I observed that $P(A,B|X) = P(B|A,X) \cdot P(A|X)$. So what I need is a function which takes as input $P(B), P(B|X)$ and $P(B|A)$ and estimates $P(B|A,X)$.

**My intuition is that I don't have enough information to logically deduce a solution. So what I want is an estimation which is as sensible as possible.**
Therefore, I made a list of necessary conditions for this function.

Firstly, in order to be probability distribution, it is necessary that

- **P:** $0 \leq P(B|A,X) \leq 1$

Then, I checked some special cases, for the values of $P(B|A)$:

- **A1:** $~P(B|A,X) \rightarrow 1~$ for $~P(B|A) \rightarrow 1, ~P(B|X) \not = 0$
- **A2:** $~P(B|A,X) = P(B|X)~$ if $~P(B|A) = P(B)$
- **A3:** $~P(B|A,X) = 0~$ if $~P(B|A) = 0$

And then also for the values of $P(B|X)$:

- **X1:** $~P(B|A,X) \rightarrow 1~$ for $~P(B|X) \rightarrow 1, ~P(B|A) \not = 0$
- **X2:** $~P(B|A,X) = P(B|A)~$ if $~P(B|X) = P(B)$
- **X3:** $~P(B|A,X) = 0~$ if $~P(B|X) = 0$

Furthermore it should hold that

- **M:** $~P(B|A,X)$ is strictly monotonically increasing in $P(B|A)$ and in $P(B|X)$.

I considered the function $P(B|A,X) = \min(1, \frac{P(B|X) \cdot P(B|A)}{P(B)})$ which satisfies **P, A2, A3, X2, X3, M** but not **A1, X1**.

Can you come up with a function that satisfies all of these constraints?

Thanks in advance for ideas :)

Comment: Do you know anything about the dependence of $A,B$ and $X$?

Comment: @stud_iisc I do only know the probabilities I have listed above and the apriori probabilities $P(A), P(B)$ (I will add them to the list)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a function which satisfies all of the above constraints and is not too complicated:

$P(B|A,X) = \min \left(1, P(B|X) \cdot P(B|A) \cdot \left[ \frac{(P(B|X)-P(B))^2 \cdot (P(B|A)-P(B))^2}{(1-P(B|X)) \cdot (1-P(B|A))} + \frac{1}{P(B)}  \right] \right)$

This is what the function looks like in a 3D-plot:

[x := P(B|X), y := P(B|A), P(B) := 0.8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqsEh.png)

I cannot give any reasons for its structure, apart from the fact that it fulfils the above necessary constraints. My intuition is that I don't have enough information to **logically deduce** a function, which is why I only asked for an **estimation which is as sensible as possible.**

So, before you downvote me, give me suggestions on how this function should be different!

Comment: @ the downvoter: can you tell me how my answer should be improved?